# Ember dependency injection doesn't work in one of our services

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

We are using ember 2.7.

in one of our `initializers/` there is a snippet to inject some app config (JSON) to all code components

```
export default {
  ...

  initialize(application) {
    application.register('appServerData:global', Ember.Object.extend(serverAppData));
    ...
    application.inject('service', 'appServerData', 'appServerData:global');
  },
  ...
}
```

The problem is in one of our services `services/local-storage.js`, `this.get('appServerData')` always returns `null`. However in other services (or controllers, routes...), it will return app config.

I have no idea how to debug on this, any clue?

======================================================

my `services/local-storage.js` is basically

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({

  // ...

  getRegion() {
    let region = this.get('appServerData.appConfig.defaultRegion') || 'US';
    return region;
  }

  // ...
});
```

where `this.get('appServerData')` always returns `null`.

Comment: I tested it with [a twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/74e97d0e4233b5d4cbf6a8603a2ec233?openFiles=services.local-storage.js%2C).

Comment: Since I can't reproduce it in the twiddle so I add local-storage methods piece by piece. In the end I found out the reason, it is because we override `get`, `set` methods in local-storage service. Thanks for your help @ykaragol